# Constructing all graphs with $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I would like to get information on what is known about the generation of all graphs with given number of edges and vertices. Specifically, $n$ vertex and $n-1$ edges.

Comment: Try drawing them for $n = 1,2,3,4$!

Comment: well i need something like 6 to 15

Comment: You'll notice a pattern. Just try it. :)

Comment: well i do not need a number of them

Comment: i need those graphs generated

Comment: Do you want labelled graphs or unlabelled graphs (i.e. non isomorphic)? Also do you want only connected graphs or all graphs?

Comment: I want unlabelled graph but not only connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the graph isomorphism software [nauty and Traces](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it). Specifically, this software package comes with a tool called `geng` that will generate all distinct unlabelled graphs of a given size and order. For example, to generate all graphs with seventeen vertices and sixteen edges, you would run

```
geng 17 16
```

This command returns $11,932,174$ graphs.